# Re-use images in an image field with drupal 8

Tags: image, drupal-8

I have created an image field and I would like to be able to select an image already used in another content.

Is there a module to do that from the "Add new file" button of the field?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

https://www.drupal.org/project/imce

IMCE is an image/file uploader and browser that supports personal directories and quota.

Comment: Don't forget to enable the extension for each image field where you want to use it, see the `README.txt` documentation that comes with the package.